# Send settings to clickhouse via http protocol using requests

Tags: python, python-requests, clickhouse

Via `clickhouse-client` code looks like this:

```
clickhouse-client --input_format_allow_errors_num=1
--input_format_allow_errors_ratio=0.1
--query="INSERT INTO db.table VALUES (..., ...., ...) FORMAT CSV"
```

I am using `requests` and my code looks like this:

```
query = 'INSERT INTO db.table VALUES (..., ...., ...) FORMAT CSV'
r = requests.post(host, data=query, auth=(CH_USER, CH_PASSWORD), verify=True)
```

how to pass settings such as

```
--input_format_allow_errors_num=1
--input_format_allow_errors_ratio=0.1
```

using `python-requests`?

Comment: Consider using the dedicated package [clickhouse_driver](https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). See example: https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/misc.html#inserting-data-from-csv-file

Comment: @vladimir i am using logs-api yandex library and it uses `requests` under the hood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you pass those settings as query parameters and the SQL query in the POST response body, though it seems like you can include that in query params as well.

```
import requests

auth = ("username", "password")
query = 'INSERT INTO db.table VALUES (..., ..., ...) FORMAT CSV'
params = {
    "input_format_allow_errors_num": 1,
    "input_format_allow_errors_ratio": 0.1
}

response = requests.post(host, data=query, params=params, auth=auth)
```

Give that a shot. I'm getting all this from: https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/http/